# How do I create an ISO (or similar) DVD of an Ubuntu setup on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, backup, dvd, clone

I need to create a DVD of a working Ubuntu, 14.04 LTS, with several software additions. I have "installed" the Ubuntu ISO on VirtualBox, updated everything, as well as added additional software items. I am in need to do this as I have a stand alone computer with no internet access but does have a DVD reader I can use to install the Ubuntu with added software. I have not found a solution looking elsewhere on the internet or here on askubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to copy the cache packages (.deb files) in your virtual machine and install it in your physical machine. 
To do this first remove all absolute packages from /var/cache/apt/archives in your virtual machine

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and copy the .deb files to your physical system and do

```
cd <path to deb files>
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

this will install all the packages to your physical system

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I have no idea what it means? I need to create a DVD that I can take to a physical machine based on the "install" I have on the virtual machine running on my host machine. I am not sure how to take your suggestions and turn them into a solution? Also, will the other software I have installed, e.g. CUDA toolkit, be located in the "deb" files you have mentioned?

Comment: you installed ubuntu on a virtual right ?

Comment: Yes. I used virtualbox.

Comment: all the packages installed in your virtual machine will be located in the directory mentioned above. installed ubuntu in your physical machine and do as above. all the .deb files will be in that directory (if you haven't cleared them in your virtual machine).